# What is broken within this nested if statement?

Tags: excel-formula

Why is the output from the middle functions (values that should output "Small 2, Mid 2, and Large 2) returning N/A?

```
=IF([@[BED/BATH]] = "0-1", "Studio", 
    IF(AND([@SQFT] < 700, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "1-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1.5")), "Small 1", 
    IF(AND([@SQFT] < 850, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "1-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1.5")), "Mid 1", 
    IF(AND([@SQFT] >= 850, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "1-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1.5")), "Large 1", 
    IF(AND([@SQFT] < 1050, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "2-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2"), [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2.5"), "Small 2", 
    IF(AND([@SQFT] < 1200, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "2-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2"), [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2.5"), "Mid 2", 
    IF(AND([@SQFT] >= 1200, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "2-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2"), [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2.5"), "Large 2", 
    IF(AND([@SQFT] < 1100, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2", [@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2.5")), "Small 3", 
    IF(AND([@SQFT] < 1300, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2", [@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2.5")), "Mid 3", 
    IF(AND([@SQFT] > 1300, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2", [@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2.5")), "Large 3", "N/A"))))))))))
```

Comment: Please, try to make the code more readable!

Comment: First Bed/Bath check is 0-1, the rest are 1-0?

Comment: What are the SQFT & BED/BATH values when it's returning #N/A?

Comment: The function for 0-1 correctly returns "Studio", the functions for Small, Mid and Large 1's correctly return, and the Small, Mid, and Large 3's correctly return, but for some reason the Small, Mid, and Large 2's are not returning correctly. So it is something weird specifically about those middle functions.

Comment: The SQFT values are several values between 678 and 1937 and the BED/BATH values are "2-0", "2-1", "2-2", and "2-2.5".

Comment: looking at just the pattern and not going through the logic.  you 1-x and 3-x ranges for you ors end in )) where as your 2-x has ) at then end of 2-1 then another ) at then end of 2-2.5.  I believe you need to delete the first ) and change the one after 2.25 to ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three brackets in the wrong place.

Your Small 2, Mid 2 and Large 2 `IF` formula have the `[@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2.5"` outside of your OR statement.

```
IF(AND([@SQFT] < 1050, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "2-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2"), [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2.5"), "Small 2",
```

should be

```
IF(AND([@SQFT] < 1050, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "2-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2.5")), "Small 2",
```

The close bracket after `"2-2"` has been moved to after `"2-2.5"`.

Final formula should be:

```
=IF([@[BED/BATH]] = "0-1", "Studio",
IF(AND([@SQFT] < 700, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "1-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1.5")), "Small 1",
IF(AND([@SQFT] < 850, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "1-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1.5")), "Mid 1",
IF(AND([@SQFT] >= 850, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "1-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "1-1.5")), "Large 1",
IF(AND([@SQFT] < 1050, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "2-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2.5")), "Small 2",
IF(AND([@SQFT] < 1200, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "2-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2.5")), "Mid 2",
IF(AND([@SQFT] >= 1200, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "2-0", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-1", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2", [@[BED/BATH]] = "2-2.5")), "Large 2",
IF(AND([@SQFT] < 1100, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2", [@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2.5")), "Small 3",
IF(AND([@SQFT] < 1300, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2", [@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2.5")), "Mid 3",
IF(AND([@SQFT] > 1300, OR([@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2", [@[BED/BATH]] = "3-2.5")), "Large 3", "N/A"))))))))))
```